# Is nvcc necessary for pytorch to use GPU

Tags: docker, pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to create a custom Docker image from scratch with NVIDIA GPU support.

I've made some progress, as I can successfully run the nvidia-smi command within the Docker container, and I've also tested GPU support with Python using python -c 'import torch; print(torch.cuda.is_available())', which returns "True." However, I'm encountering an issue with the nvcc -V command, which does not work as expected compared to the TensorFlow Docker image.

My question is:
Is nvcc necessary when working with pytorch?

Comment: If `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns `True`, you should be set. Double check by doing some tensor computation on GPU and verify.